# Gossiping custom fields in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, gossip

I wanted to know if we can gossip user defined values in cassandra. I'm looking at the [Gossiper.java](https://github.com/facebookarchive/cassandra/blob/master/src/org/apache/cassandra/gms/Gossiper.java) file to understand the workflow, but so far have been unable to figure how to add custom fields for gossiping in cassandra. I'm a novice when it comes to cassandra and would appreciate it if anyone could guide me in this regard. Thanks !

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Gossip is an internal protocol of Cassandra, it has not user-facing interface, it's not meant to be modified.

Comment: I'm trying to add custom fields along with predefined parameters like DC, RACK to be gossiped. I wanted to know how it can be done.

Comment: You will probably need to check / modify the source code of Cassandra to alter the gossip protocol. Before going there, it would be useful to tell us your endgoal. Why do you want to add some variables, what are thoses etc... Maybe there is a better way to achieve your goal than altering the gossip protocol...